# Не работает вывод текста при смени варианта (select)

Tags: jquery, select

```
    <select name="id" id="ProductSelect" class="product-form__variants no-js">
              <option data-tag="S" selected="selected" ">
                one
              </option>
              <option data-tag="M"  ">
                two
              </option>
    </select>
```

Мне надо выводить console.log, когда у нас выбран S, а не M!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#ProductSelect").change(function () {
  console.log('hello!');
   var selected =  $(this).val();
$( "#ProductSelect option:selected" ).each(function() {
     console.log(selected);
     var element =  $(this);
     console.log(element.data("tag"));

    if (element.data("tag") === 'S'){
      alert('DONE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Я делаю проверки:
console.log('hello!')   - она уже не выводится в консоле. 
Очень нужна помощь!
Я не понимаю чего оно не работает?

```js
$("#ProductSelect").change(function() {
  console.log('hello!');
  var selected = $(this).val();
  $("#ProductSelect option:selected").each(function() {
    console.log(selected);
    var element = $(this);
    console.log(element.data("tag"));

    if (element.data("tag") === 'S') {
      alert('DONE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="id" id="ProductSelect" class="product-form__variants no-js">
  <option data-tag="S" selected="selected">
    one
  </option>
  <option data-tag="M">
    two
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Что не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#ProductSelect").on('change', function() {
    //код
});
```

https://codepen.io/xhonor/pen/MWWbbYV

Answer (score 0):

Уберите лишние двойные кавычки в тагах `option`:

```
          <option data-tag="S" selected="selected" ">
          ...
          <option data-tag="M"  ">
```